# A step in an induction proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a_1, b_1$ are positive numbers such that $a_1 < b_1$ and two sequences of positive numbers are defined by $a_{n + 1} = \sqrt{a_nb_n}$ and $b_{n + 1} = \frac 12(a_n + b_n)$, prove that $0 < a_n < a_{n + 1} < b_{n + 1} < b_n$.

claim: $b_{n + 2} < b_{n + 1}$

$b_{n + 2} = \frac12(a_{n + 1} + b_{n +1})$

$b_{n + 1} = \frac12(a_n + b_n)$

$b_{n + 2} = \frac12(\sqrt {a_nb_n} + \frac12(a_n + b_n))$

I am not sure how to justify the step below

$\frac12(a_n + b_n) > \frac12(\sqrt {a_nb_n} + \frac12(a_n + b_n))$

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn’t work that hard. You know that $a_{n+1}<b_{n+1}$, so

$$b_{n+2}=\frac12(a_{n+1}+b_{n+1})<\frac12(b_{n+1}+b_{n+1})=b_{n+1}\;.$$

Comment: Just starting to get used to the tricks and tips of working with real numbers. :) Thanks.

Comment: @user316242: You’re welcome.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, Is it ok if I ask one more question? If in addition to the givens in OP we know that $0 < b_{n + 1} - a_{n + 1} < b_{n + 1} - a_n = \frac12(b_n - a_n)$, how can we do the inductive step of $0 < b_{n + 1} - a_{n + 1} < (\frac12)^n(b_1 - a_1)?$ I tried real hard, but wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: @user316242: Your induction hypothesis is that $b_n-a_n<\left(\frac12\right)^n(b_1-a_1)$. Now you have $$b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}<\frac12(b_n-a_n)<\frac12\left(\frac12\right)^n(b_n-a_n)\;,$$ and you’re practically there.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, Awesome! I was soooo stuck here. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @user316242: My pleasure; glad it helped!

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, Sorry to bother you again, but I think I made a mistake somewhere. These two uploads([Link 1](http://s14.postimg.org/kzm7e5ytt/1111.png), [Link 2](http://s15.postimg.org/m62z4d4ez/11111.png)) actually show what's going on. Apparently, I am supposed to use induction and problem (ii) to solve problem (iii).

Comment: @user316242: You’re okay: the argument that I gave for (iii) is the induction step of an induction using (ii).